# Ionic android facebook login not working?

Tags: android, facebook, cordova

Logging in with Facebook on ios works well, but when I installed it on an android device the result was `Session was closed and was not closed normally` and possibly another error that I don't remember, currently I do not have an android device on me.

I have tried following these steps [Phonegap/Cordova facebook login not working when already connected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27893080/phonegap-cordova-facebook-login-not-working-when-already-connected)

1. I generated a keystore
2. I generated a hash for the keystore
3. Added that to developers.facebook inside my app within the android platform

THE REMAINING STEPS I CANT DO THIS AS I AM USING IONIC... I DID HOWEVER ADD A `release-signing.properties` file with

```
key.store=./app.keystore
key.store.password=****
key.alias=app
key.alias.password=****
```

I am really clueless as to why I cant login with facebook on an android device with ionic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to unlink app from your facebook account from settings->apps->look for "logged in with facebook" tab->(select your application) and remove app from logged-in account. And then retry login.